# Are there techniques for calibrating thresholds for Canny edge detection by using feedback from Stroke-Width Transform?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, edge-detection

As described in the Stroke-Width Transform (SWT) paper, it uses the output of Canny edge detection as its input. This puts the accuracy of the Canny edge detection in a critical position, because if the accuracy is low (say, too much noise, or missing too much correct edges), SWT will either find too much spurious results or miss some text strokes entirely.

The hysteresis parameters used in Canny edge detection is notoriously difficult to tune when the nature of input image is unconstrained.

Are there any documented approaches of using the partially correct (i.e. partially inaccurate) results of SWT to improve on the parameter selection of the Canny edge detection step, such that the two steps can be iterated to produce successive refinement?

*(One of my intended usage is on scanned document images. Unfortunately, I do not have any sample images that I can post publicly. Moreover, being able to handle unconstrained images containing text is a side goal that is still moderately important in the long run.)*

Comment: I stumbled upon this question while researching for my own SWT Project.  I was able to get decent canny images with text edges by choosing the lower hysteresis as the Otsu threshold and the upper one as 2*Otsu Threshold value. After this I filtered it with MSER by assuming, that text areas are rather stable image areas. By dilating the MSER result and boolean AND it with the canny result i was able to eliminate many non-text edges. It's far from perfect and no solution for a very good Canny hysteresis but i hope this filter method is helpfull.